# Streamlit Markdown html styling with latex

Tags: html, latex, markdown, streamlit

I am trying to use streamlit's [markdown](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/text/st.markdown) writing element with a custom css class and a latex command that acts as a "tab" (four spaces). In this example I am using hspace.

Streamlit's markdown allows for custom css classes by setting `unsafe_allow_html=True`. Streamlit also has declared that they [support latex commands](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/text/st.markdown#:%7E:text=LaTeX%20expressions%2C%20by%20wrapping%20them%20in%20%22%24%22%20or%20%22%24%24%22%20(the%20%22%24%24%22%20must%20be%20on%20their%20own%20lines).%20Supported%20LaTeX%20functions%20are%20listed%20at%20https%3A//katex.org/docs/supported.html.).

I have been able to use latex command in st.markdown(). However it appears that when I had html to include the custom class, it no longer works. Is there a specific format that I am not following? Am I overlooking something?

python=3.10
streamlit=1.31.0

```
import streamlit as st

# Define the CSS
custom_css = """
<style>
    .center-text {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
"""

# Inject the CSS into the app
st.markdown(custom_css, unsafe_allow_html=True)

# hspace command
tab = r'$\hspace{1cm}$'
```

```
st.markdown(f'<p class="center-text">This{tab}text is spaced.</p>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
>>> This$\hspace{1cm}$text is spaced.
```

```
st.markdown(f'This{tab}text is spaced.')
>>> This    text is spaced.
```